# Existence and uniqueness of solution of $x^{\prime}(t) = \frac{t-x}{1+x^2}$ where $x(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

I want to show, that there exists a unique solution for the IVP
$$\begin{cases}x^\prime(t) = \frac{t-x}{1+x^2},x(0)=0 \end{cases}$$
and find the maximum interval of existence. I have tried multiple substitutions to solve it, nothing leads anywhere. I also thought about finding a minorant for $x^\prime(t)$, though I don't really see, how that could help me.

Comment: To start with, there's the well known Picard–Lindelöf theorem. Discussing its application in this problem would be a good start, if you're willing to show your efforts.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4027662/initial-value-problem-of-nonlinear-first-order-ode someone's assignment I suppose